# Does This Property of Words Have a Name?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, definition, combinatorics-on-words

Let us say an infinite word $w=w_1w_2\cdots$ over a finite alphabet $\{a_1,\ldots,a_r\}$ is *good* if there exists a positive integer $m$ such that none of the words $a_1^m,\ldots,a_r^m$ appear as factors of $w$. Equivalently, saying $w$ is good means that it does not contain arbitrarily long factors that use only one letter. Does this "good" property already have a different name in the literature?

Comment: It's an example of "shift of finite type" .  But there are other examples not of this form.

Comment: As mentioned, the set of sequences $X_{\mathcal{F}}$ such that no word in the finite set $\mathcal{F} = \{a_i^m \mid 1 \leq i \leq r\}$ appears in any sequence in $X_{\mathcal{F}}$ is called a *shift of finite type* (SFT) or *topological Markov shift*. You might also be interested in the related notion of *square-free* and *$k$-free* sequences (not quite the same, but of the same spirit).